# routerLinkActive problems

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

So, I have a menu on a page. I have the `routerLinkActive` attribute, which should add a green background if the link is active. If not active it should be grey. The problem is that, even though the `bg-success` class is added, it won't overwrite the `bg-dark` class.

My question is, do you guys have any ideea how I could make this work? I would have the option to go in and modify the bootstrap file, and remove `"!important"` from `bg-dark`, but I don't want to mess with that.

Maybe something in angular, like, `routerLinkNotActive`, which would allow me to swap the classes.

```
<a class="list-group-item bg-dark text-light" [routerLink]="'/admin-dashboard'" routerLinkActive="bg-success" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Dashboard</a>
```

Comment: import your global css file after bootstrap css file 
like this  ['./node-module/bootstrap.min.css']
              ['./assets/global.css']  in global css file bg-success class should be !important

Comment: @RavindraGupta both classes are from bootstrap

Comment: then make another class in your global css file what's big deal

Comment: @RavindraGupta the big deal is that he will have to create class that already exists.

Comment: so don't create a class with same name create another new with new name for specific action

Comment: @RavindraGupta It's about best practices, not about the name of the class.

Comment: @trichetriche Is right. I could have done that, rewriting a new class, but I was sure there was a better solution. And it is the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around that thanks to the `exportAs` property of Angular. Luckily for you, it's already in the [**routerLinkActive**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) property :

```html
<a 
  class="list-group-item text-light" 
  [routerLink]="'/admin-dashboard'"
  routerLinkActive
  #rla="routerLinkActive" 
  [class.bg-success]="rla.isActive" 
  [class.bg-dark]="!rla.isActive" 
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Dashboard</a>
```

`exportAs` allows you to create a template variable which is actually an instance of the class you're exporting. This means `rla instanceof RouterLinkActive` will return true.

In your case, you can use the `isActive` property of the class to check if the link is active. If it is, then you can chose which class to use.

Comment: I get the following error when I try this: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "routerLinkActive". Any ideea why?

Comment: Try with `RouterLinkActive` then (capitalized)

Comment: Ok, I made it work. I had to add the attribute `routerLinkActive` to the `a` tag. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Woops, forgot that ! No problem, I'm editing my answer